# Watson iOS SDK authentication

Tags: ios, facebook, oauth-2.0, ibm-cloud, ibm-watson

I've been looking at https://github.com/rfdickerson/watson-translation-demo which attempts to show how to do authentication using Facebook OAuth on iOS and with a NodeJS Backend.

The iOS code is straightforward :

```
let token: String = FBSDKAccessToken.currentAccessToken().tokenString

let fbAccess = FacebookAuthenticationStrategy(
    tokenURL: "https://watsonsdkdemo.mybluemix.net/language-translation-service/api/v1/token",
    fbToken: token)
translateService = LanguageTranslation(authStrategy: fbAccess)
```

The problem is that the server/app.js has

```
var creds = appEnv.getServiceCreds(/facebook-authentication/) || {}
```

and the manifest.yml has

```
- services:
  - facebook-authentication
```

But when you `cf push` the scripts to your Bluemix account you get:

```
FAILED
Could not find service facebook-authentication to bind to xxxxxxx
```

The problem is nowhere does the author describe what the 'facebook-authentication" service is.

In the server deployment instructions they have

```
$ cf login
$ cf create-service speech_to_text standard speech-to-text-service
$ cf create-service text_to_speech standard text-to-speech-service
$ cf create-service language_translation standard language-translation-service
$ cf env
$ cd server
$ cf push
```

Nothing stating what the facebook-authentication service is.

Comment: I messaged the author of the repo and asked him to respond.

Answer (score 0):

I apologize that the instructions are incomplete. facebook-authentication is supposed to be a user-provided service. You can create it using the [cf create-user-provided-service command](https://developer.ibm.com/answers/questions/16290/how-to-create-a-custom-service-which-exposes-some-rest-apis.html):

cf create-user-provided-service facebook-authentication -p "APP_SECRET_GOES_HERE"

The idea is that when you register a Facebook application, they give you an App Secret. Since that secret should not be embedded in the source code, you can set it in the environment variables VCAP by creating a custom service that provides that information for you.

Note, I did not finish actually using the app secret to check the legitimacy of the credentials. Although this is a small security vulnerability for man-in-the-middle-attacks, the facebook token checking still works because in the Facebook App settings I made it so that using the App secret is not required. For now, just create the user service and set the value to anything you would like.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Ok, it works! when I supply the "APP_SECRET_GOES_HERE" on the command line  for whatever reason it gives me a ">" prompt.  In checking the command help it seems to say it's like 
 cf create-user-provided-service my-db-mine -p '{"username":"admin","password":"pa55woRD"}' 

Actually I typed exit in the > prompt and in the bluemix web interface environment variables it shows it as 
"user-provided": [
      {
         "name": "facebook-authentication",
         "label": "user-provided",
         "credentials": {
            "APP_SECRET_GOES_HERE": "exit"
         }
      }
   ]